# I was able to pass username and password to webservice, but its not the way i need to secure from unauthorized user

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, authentication, iis-7

This is another question I have about web services and securing them. I made a WCF Web Service and this is the code that I used...

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET")]
    string myData(string name, string pass);
```

and this is the code that I use to interact with the web service...

```
    public string myData(string a, string b)
    {
        if (a == "chris" && b == "pass")
            return "You did it";
        else
            return "Nope";
    }
```

I know this looks basic and I understand that I can add more functionality to it, but I don't think this is the way I need. It looks a little dirty to me.

If have a web service sitting on a server and if someone tries to use the service, I would like a pop up to ask for a username and password, so I can verify that they are in the database and they can proceed invoking the web service.

For this to be done, should I set up authentication in IIS to do this? I think I'm over thinking things.
My client just wants me to be able to secure the web service from unauthorized users. So That's what I am running into an issue with, I'm not sure the correct way to secure everything from unauthorized access, should (and how) this be done in IIS or just use the code that I provided.

I apologize if this kind of question has been asked a million times but the question is always different and so are the answers.

Comment: Did you try to search for ["secure wcf service"](https://www.google.com/search?q=secure+wcf+service)? Among other things, you'll find ["Windows Communication Foundation Security"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732362.aspx).

Comment: Yes I have. I was asked this "Whats the best way to ensure security in a web service so that outside people can't access the information" as well to briefly test it. I guess the question I should have asked him if it was going online or on an intranet, or both. I guess if I knew that answer then I would have asked a better question. Maybe since the inside people use it then outside of it I could just provide a login page, have it check from a database then if so then I could direct the page to where there service are and use buttons to run them? Would that do the same thing?

Comment: Really. Please read up on web services. You should at least understand what's possible instead of just choosing the first thing that looks like it might be a solution. I understand that you're just learning, but when I was learning, I found it very important to read first, write code second.

Comment: I have been reading up on Web Services, and I am getting an understanding of it, not quick as I'd like, but on the path (with your direction from a question that I had earlier). I don't think that I was choosing the first thing that looked like a solution, its more natural for me because anything I ever wrote has been database driven, But nonetheless, it is a workable solution, providing security, just not the norm? depending on what I am learning, I also find it important to read first, but when its just reading its just theory, So I read and code along at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

You should set your authentication method say forms authentication 
    
    
and set you credential in request. Also better do it as HTTPS.